Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, Swap works sometimes, and sometimes crashes python
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, 64-bit, 64Gb RAM
Python: 3.9.19
Summary:

Running memory-intensive analysis in Python causes python to crash most of the time, but not always.
Crashes happen specifically when RAM is exhausted and Python starts using virtual memory.
Other programs (ImageJ) are able to use virtual memory without crashing, making it seem like python specifically was the problem.
Analysis was originally being run in Anaconda3, in an environment running python 3.9, but the crashing behavior persisted in a different anaconda environment running python 3.11, and also when running in the Ubuntu 22.04 native python 3.10.
When python crashes, it does not generate any dmesg() report.
Increasing swap file size does not help.
Adding a swap file on a different drive does not help.
Increasing or decreasing vm.swappiness does not help.
Changing the vm.overcommit_memory behavior does not help.
journalctl -xe actually did include a report of the crash, indicating that system-oomd was killing processes due to high memory pressure, though the reported memory use stats didn't match with the memory use logged by System Monitor.

Original Question:
I have an essentially brand-new ubuntu machine, and I've been trying to use it to perform some memory-intensive processing in python.
Initially, I was having a problem where any time I tried doing anything memory-intenstive, my python kernel would be killed, and I'd get an "insufficient memory" error in python.
I discovered that somehow when I installed Ubuntu initially, my swap file was sized to 2gb, which was obviously the problem. I set up a new file that's 120gb instead, and I haven't gotten that problem again.
Instead, I'm having this thing happen where 80% of the time, when python runs out of RAM and starts using swap, python just totally crashes and closes. No error messages, and nothing added to the dmesg log, it just closes.
The particularly annoying thing about this is that this only happens 80% of the time. 20% of the time, running identical code with everything else exactly the same, the program runs totally fine with no problems at all. It uses up the RAM, and starts using the swap, and as long as it doesn't run out of swap, everything go though successfully.
I've tried changing swappiness, and that doesn't seem to have any effect at all. I noticed that the priority on my swap file was set to -1, so I changed it first to 1, and then to 0, and neither of those things worked.
I even tried running a little snippet of code in python that just eats up memory, to see if the problem was specifically with the analysis I was running, but no. RAM gets used up, the swap file uses 7-12gb of the 120gb allocated, and then python crashes.
Update:
I tried adding a second swap file on my 8tb internal storage HDD, in addition to the swap file on my 2tb OS disk, and that worked for a little while. The python script would hit 99% RAM use, then write things to swap, and the RAM use would drop temporarily, and so on. After running the script a few times, however, the behavior reverted to the previous state, where RAM use rises to 99%, swap use increases to ~10gb, but the RAM use never drops, the swap use stops increasing, and then python crashes.

@kos, I have run it on the same data set, and had it either run successfully, or crash, in apparently identical conditions. Also, the fact that I got exactly the same crash behavior running a totally different script (see last paragraph) seems like a strong indication that the problem is not with the script, it's with the swap, or the way that python is using swap.

Ah my bad, I misread the last paragraph (I understood it wasn't crashing in that case). And no output from sudo dmesg | grep Killed, correct?

Yeah, nothing at all from dmesg on that.

I've also tried changing vm.overcommit_memory to 1 or 2: no change.
Also tried setting vm.dirty_ratio to 10: no change.

You mention Ubuntu, but provide no clues as to what product (Server? Core? Desktop?) nor what release of that product. Why not tell us instead of making us guess, as software changes over time, and you've not yet told us how old/new your Ubuntu stack is.

My mistake; I've added information about my version of Ubuntu and Python.

Your details don't make sense for a Ubuntu system; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS does not use python3 3.9 as the 2022-April released used a later version of python3; your python3 version only matches an EOL release from 2019 or a corrupted/non-Ubuntu system - I'd explore what you're actually running!

@guiverc my default version of python is Python 3.11.7, but I'm running 3.9.19 in an environment for compatibility reasons, because my python 3.11.7 refuses to use Mamba at all.

@guiverc also, I just tried running a memory-eating test script in the base 3.11.7 environment, and it worked exactly once. Used up all the RAM, started using swap. I killed it at 70gb, and I think it would have just kept going. Then I tried it 2 more times, and both times it crashed at ~10gb swap use, exactly like the behavior in the 3.9.19 environment, so I don't think that the environment or python version are at fault.

I ultimately wiped my OS and did a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04 instead. Since then, python has been able to use virtual memory successfully without crashing.
Still not sure what exactly the root of the problem was, but this seems to have fixed it.
